# Not able to move cursor along the text on editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to find answer on other threads in stackoverflow, but couldn't really find it. 
I am implementing a `TextWatcher`, when I start typing the text it moves to the initial position and keeps on adding the text on the right side.
So I added  `edittext.setSelection(scene.getText().length());` to move the cursor to extreme right, but now when I click on the text on anywhere, the cursor moves to the initial position and doesn't work anymore.
I want my cursor to move along the text as I type it, what should I do.
Here is my `TextWatcher`

```
scene.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //here is your code
        strcheck = s.toString().substring((s.length() - 1), s.length());

        if (nowUpper)
            strcheck = strcheck.toUpperCase();
        else if (nowLower)
            strcheck = strcheck.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (nowUpper) {
            if (ix == 1) {
                ix = 0;
                scene.setText(scene.getText().toString().substring(0,scene.length() - 1) + strcheck);
                // scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());
            } else {
                ix = 1;
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you've added 2 Edit Texts - Probani